# Inject an operation using a remote node

Tags: node, inject

I would like to inject an operation (specifically, send a transaction) from my notebook, which has a compiled node but its blockchain is not synced, using my Ledger Nano X. My other computer has a synced node and I would like to inject the transaction remotely.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please accept answer below if that's good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Tell your tezos-client to use a public RPC node that accepts injections (not all do).

`tezos-client -A https://publicrpc.node.com/ transfer 50 from tz1.. to tz1...`

You'll need to find a public RPC that allows injections. I think https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io/ does